# How does partial ordering of function templates work?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization

The section [[temp.func.order]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order) describes a complicated process by which it is determined whether one function template is more specialized than another. I am having trouble visualizing, and understanding how this process actually works.

Could you explain which sections in the standard apply in this simple example?

```cpp
template <typename T, int N>
struct array { T data[N]; };

template <typename T>
void foo(T);           // #1

template <typename T, int N>
void foo(array<T, N>); // #2

template <typename T>
void foo(array<T, 1>); // #3


// call: foo(array<int, 1>{})
```

It's intuitively obvious `#3` is more specialized than `#2`, which is more specialized than `#1`, but how is this really determined in the standard?

Comment: Well, in standard C++, your attempt to instantiate a class containing a member that is an array of size 0 makes your program ill-formed.

Comment: @BrianBi that was an oversight but it's also not important for this question. I've changed it to `1`.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea behind partial ordering is not very complicated. First, let's rename some of the `T`'s:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T);           // #1

template <typename U, int N>
void foo(array<U, N>); // #2

template <typename V>
void foo(array<V, 1>); // #3
```

The idea is that every `array<U, N>` is a `T`, but not every `T` is an `array<U, N>`. That makes #2 more specialized than #1.

And every `array<V, 1>` is an `array<U, N>`, but not every `array<U, N>` is an `array<V, 1>` (since `N` might not be 1). That makes #3 more specialized than #2.

In order to check whether every `array<U, N>` is a `T`, we replace `U` with a "unique type" and `N` with a "unique value". Call these `UniqT1` and `uniqv1`. Then, we get the type `array<UniqT1, uniqv1>` and we attempt to deduce `T` from this. That's easy: it's just `T` = `array<UniqT1, uniqv1>`. Then we also try the same thing the other way around: is every `T` an `array<U, N>`? To determine this, we replace `T` with `UniqT2` and attempt to deduce `U` and `N` in `array<U, N>`. Since the type `UniqT2` is "unique", there is no way to make `array<U, N>` the same type as `UniqT2` no matter what `U` and `N` are.

Similarly when you replace `V` in #3 with a unique type, you can deduce `U` and `N` in #2, but you can't do it the other way around: replace `U` and `N` with a unique type and unique value in #2, and then you can't deduce `V` in #3, because `N`, being a unique value, isn't equal to 1. That implies that #3 is more specialized than #2.

Now as for the standard wording:

The "synthesize a unique type/value" rule is [[temp.func.order]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order#3).

Then [[temp.func.order]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order#4) tells you to perform deduction after substituting the unique types/values.

[[temp.deduct.partial]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#10) tells you how to interpret the result: if deduction only succeeds in one of the two directions, then whichever template's arguments are the ones that *could* be deduced, that one is the less specialized one.

In the context of a call, I should additionally mention that according to [[temp.deduct.partial]/3.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#3.1) any parameter types for which no actual argument was provided in the call are ignored.

The details of the rules are of course enormously complicated, so my summary of "every X is a Y but not vice versa" does not come close to explaining the whole thing. The additional rules cover situations like parameters of reference type, comparing non-static member functions with static member functions, and variadic templates.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea of partial ordering is that one tries **deducing** the template arguments for template 1 from the parameter types of template 2.  If deduction succeeds, template 2 is at least as specialized as template 1.

Deduction trivially succeeds for #1 from anything since its declared parameter type is just `T`.  #2 similarly succeeds from #3 since we can deduce `T`<sub>2</sub>=`T`<sub>3</sub> and `N`<sub>2</sub>=0.  The other directions do not succeed, so the obvious **total** order emerges in this particular case.

Comment: IMHO, the last sentence is confusing as it may let think that partial ordering can lead to total ordering. It's the case here, thus there is non ambiguity but it is possible, with other design, that in a pair of specializations, not one can be considered as more specialized than the other, leading to possible ambiguity. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Oersted: Of course.  I would expect that the term “partial ordering” makes that obvious, but I edited in a small clarification.